# Getting Error message while installng seaborn using pip

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, seaborn, installation-package

I am getting an error in my Ubuntu terminal while installing seaborn for python 2.7.
The command goes as follows:

```
pip install seaborn
```

The ERROR goes as follows:

```
Collecting seaborn
Installing collected packages: seaborn
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn-0.8.dist-info'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. What I did was went back to the terminal and typed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-seaborn
```

For python3 we can type as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-seaborn
```

Then go back to IPython Notebook and:

```
import seaborn
```